# Suspend main thread in qt

Tags: multithreading, qt, suspend

I want to make a function that stops the main thread and restarts restarts it after a couple of seconds. I tried the following:

```
void Mainwindow::timeout()
{
    QTimer timer;
    timer.setSingleShot(true);
    timer.setInterval(time*1000);
    connect(&timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),MainWindow::thread(),SLOT(start()));

    timer.start();

    SuspendThread(MainWindow::thread());
}
```

Unfortunately this doesnt do a whole lot... Any tips?

Comment: Why? First rule of UI programming: never block the UI thread, ever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am overlooking something, but a "function that stops [...] and restarts after a couple of seconds" sounds like `sleep()` to me. Let the OS do the timing instead of re-inventing the wheel.

Or is there any reason you can't post some message to the main thread? In this simple use case maybe even via a single mutex would be enough. Set the mutex from another thread, check it in the main threads event loop and possibly call `sleep()` directly.

That also eases debugging, as you have a single place the main thread will go sleeping willingly instead of being suspendend on the fly by other threads.

Answer (score 3):

your timer object is destroyed at the end of the the `Mainwindow::timeout()` function, so it will never emit its `timeout()` signal.

Comment: Also, if you block the main thread and not return to the event loop, the timer timeout wouldn't get triggered anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you would want to stop event loop, but you can sleep your thread by waiting on locked mutex for x milliseconds.

In the code below you will use `waitCondition.wait(&mutex, msecs);` to wait on  a condition variable for maximum `msecs` milliseconds. Since mutex is locked, as there is no another thread which will send wake up signal, this will block your thread for `timeout` milliseconds. Reference is [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qwaitcondition.html#wait).

```
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <QMutex>

class Sleep
{
public:
    static void msleep(unsigned long msecs)
    {
        QMutex mutex;
        mutex.lock();

        QWaitCondition waitCondition;
        waitCondition.wait(&mutex, msecs);

        mutex.unlock(); // Not necessary since new mutex will always be created,
                        // but since destroying locked mutex
                        // is bringing undefined behavior, let's follow some ethics 
    }
};
```

Comment: I am not quite used to qt thread handling, so maybe I am overlooking something. But doesn't your approach always block the calling thread (or to put it in another way: Is semantically a `sleep()` call)? The OP asked how to block another thread.

Comment: @MarcusRiemer Yes, this is semantically a sleep() call. Unfortunately, I didn't see that OP asked to block another thread - why do you think that he want to block another thread? Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea ... And looking at the first comment to the question, it seems quite a few people aren't sure what the OP is actually trying to achieve.

Comment: I agree - so, there is +1 for your answer :).